# Print icon for taxonomy terms

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

In my wordpress theme `Taxonomy = my-category` & categories are `AB,AC,AD` etc for custom post type.

I want to print icons for custom categories, and using `if & else` statement inside `wp_query` on `index.php` below is my code.

```
 $args = array(
 'post_type'      => 'mycpt',
 'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); 
    the_content();

if ($term_id === 10){
    echo '<p class="icon-gear"></p>';
}
else if ($term_id === 11){
    echo '<p class="icon-star"></p>';
}
else if ($term_id === 12){
    echo '<p class="icon-tv"></p>';
}   
 //and continuous  ..............
}
}
```

**CSS**

```
 .icon-gear:before { background:url('gear.svg') no-repeat; }
 .icon-star:before { background:url('star.svg') no-repeat; }
 .icon-tv:before { background:url('tv.svg') no-repeat; }
```

**How to print svg icon for taxonomy categories?**

Comment: if you are going to use an if else like that, use a switch instead. You can also avoid duplicate code by saying `switch ($term_id) case 10: $icon = "star";` and then `echo "<p class='icon-$icon'";` Can you tell what is going wrong? Because you say what you want to happen, but not what is happening now.

Comment: Where are you getting `$term_id` from?

Comment: @ikdekker its not showing any thing. empty box with no error

Comment: if you  inspect the html by looking at the page-source, have the <p> elements appeared? if so can you try deleting the :before from the css.

Comment: @ikdekker in page-source its empty. `<p>` not show

Comment: Okay, can you make sure the $term_ids match with the 10 and 11

Comment: I am getting term_id from browser URL bar, when i go to category edit page. `localhost/wordpress/term.php?taxonomy=my-category&tag_ID=10&post_type=mycpt&wp_ht.......`

Comment: I ment, where are you setting your `$term_id` variable - something like `$termArray = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'my-category'); $term_id = $termArray[0];`

Comment: ^înside your `while` loop

Comment: if you `var_dump($term_id);` now, are you getting a number, bool(false) or a string?

Comment: @Stender i get `NULL`

Comment: @ikdekker yes term_ids match and correct

Comment: @F.A If you get `NULL` it means that it doesn't know what you are looking for - you need to set your variable, before you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested code, try this

```
 $args = array(
 'post_type'      => 'mycpt',
 'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); 
    the_content();

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'my-category');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $termID[] = $term->term_id;
}
if ($termID[0] === 10){
    echo '<p class="icon-gear"></p>';
}
else if ($termID[0] === 11){
    echo '<p class="icon-star"></p>';
}
else if ($termID[0] === 12){
    echo '<p class="icon-tv"></p>';
}   
 //and continuous  ..............
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the wrong way to go about it and is not maintainable.

Personally, I would be looking into using custom fields to add a text field to your categories and you can set the icon for each one through the dashboard. Then you just have to echo one custom field during your loop and can default to blank/default icon if it is empty.

Look into Advanced Custom Fields plugin if you are not already using it.

Comment: I would like if can achieve without plugin. is possible?

Comment: Yes, it would be a lot easier with ACF, but if you prefer not having a plugin take a look at this guide: https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/

Comment: Problem is that every plugin including ACF only show images on `taxonomy.php` or `category.php`  not on index. I Already mention in question need to print on index.php

Comment: ACF Should be able to do this on index as well - when you query on index, it shows as cat and tax as well